# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '3.5' to data type int with Convert()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Column `ReduceDuties.Confirmed_Time` is : (`Nvarchar` type)

```
  Confirmed_Time
|----------------|
|       5        | 
|       3.5      |
|       10       |
|       15       |
|       18       |
```

I want to classify numbers.

**Output desired:**

```
1-9   =>  2
9-19  =>  3
```

I have tried:

```
    select t.range as [score range], count(*) as [number of occurences]
from (
      select convert (float , Confirmed_Time) as Taeid,
         case when Confirmed_Time >= 1 and Confirmed_Time <= 9 then '0-9'
         when Confirmed_Time > 9 and Confirmed_Time <= 19 then '9-19'
         end as range
     from ReduceDuties) t
group by t.range
```

But I get the following error :

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '3.5' to data
>   type int.

Comment: Because `3.5` is not an integer value?

Comment: @solmaz ahamdi try applying `floor()` in `case when` statement, for instance, `case when floor(Confirmed_Time >= 1`...

Comment: Why are you storing numerical data as an `nvarchar` in the first place?

Comment: @Larnu I think regional formatting

Comment: One way to fix this is to specify decimal literals in the CASE expression, like `Confirmed_Time >= 1.0 and Confirmed_Time <= 9.0`.

Comment: What does regional formatting have to do with storing numerical data as an `nvarchar` @SNR ? Apart from that formatting should be handled in the presentation layer, I don't know of any regions where `2 > 10`. For the OP's data the "highest" value is `'5'` (and the lowest is `'10'`); which I doubt is intended.

Comment: @Larnu I meant for the storing floats as `nvarchar` because of the decimal mark sometimes can `.` instead of `,`. If this data is comes from a `BULK insert` you probably have to store them as `nvarchar`.

Comment: But then you would use a staging table and convert the data afterwards, @SNR. Storing numerical data as a `(n)varchar` is almost always a bad idea. The OP's post is just one example of why;  like you can't cast a string representation of a non-integer value to an `int` and hence it makes the logic "harder". the you have behaviour like I describe above (`'2' > '10000000000'`), if you were to do a query like `WHERE StringNumeric = 1` the query would be non-SARGable (or fail if you again had non-integer values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, `confirmed_time` is a string.  When you compare to an integer, it tries to compare as integers.  So, make the conversion *explicit*:

```
(case when try_convert(float, Confirmed_Time) >= 1 and
           try_convert(float, Confirmed_Time) <= 9
      then '0-9'
 . . .
```

My recommendation is to never rely on implicit conversion.  It introduces really hard to spot errors.

If you want this value as a decimal (which makes more sense to me than an int), then you should change the type in the table.  If that is not possible for some reason (say some values are not numbers), you can add a new column:

```
alter table ReduceDuties add confirmed_time_dec as (try_convert(decimal(10, 2), Confirmed_Time));
```

You can then use `confirmed_time_dec` safely in your queries.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not doing the conversion from text to numeric inside the `CASE` expression.  I might just start here with a CTE which does the conversion first:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(float, Confirmed_Time) AS Confirmed_Time
    FROM ReduceDuties
)

SELECT
    Confirmed_Time,
    CASE WHEN Confirmed_Time BETWEEN 1 AND 9  THEN '0-9'
         WHEN Confirmed_Time BETWEEN 9 AND 19 THEN '9-19'
    END AS range
FROM cte;
```

If you really intend to mainly use the confirmed time column as a number, then you should probably just make it a numeric type column.  Then, if you ever had to still occasionally use it as text, just do that conversion as needed.